# Allowing Remote MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, vb.net, permissions, vsto

I'm building an Excel app using VSTO / VB.NET and make several connections to a bunch of databases/tables in MySQL which is hosted on a BlueHost account.

Now, they require for the IP address of the inquiring computer to be registered as a 'host', which sounds great for security but given the app will be distributed to a theoretically unlimited number of people on an unlimited number of computers - it's very impractical for me to individually allow each client IP address in my BlueHost account. What's the best way to allow access, on the fly?

The database user/password will already have the correct permissions to the relevant databases etc. It's just a matter of allowing them access to a remote MYSQL connection to start off with.

I've read around SO to use the 'GRANT ALL' SQL Command but I'm not sure exactly when and where to use this. How would you run a SQL command before making a connection to the database; because it is at this point that the connection throws an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this it has all your info for conecting to remote servers too, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162132.aspx)